# Redirect route with data in Laravel Vue Inertia stack

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In my controller i have

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $postData = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required | boolean'
        ]);

        Room::create([
            'name' => $postData['name'],
            'active' => $postData['status'],
        ]);

        $message = "Room Added";

        return redirect::route('rooms.index', ['msg' => $message]);
    }
```

and i used 'msg' in my props

```
props:['rooms','errors','msg']
```

But for {{msg}} gives undefined and not any message.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're passing `msg` as a param to your route, not as a param to your `Inertia::render` call. And since you're redirecting, you probably want to flash the message to the session and handle it on the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware. Look into the [example in the documentation](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages).

So, first you redirect to `rooms.index` flashing the message:

```php
return redirect()->route('rooms.index')->with('message', 'My message');
```

Then, Inertia requests the `rooms.index` route as a XHR request and before it hits your Controller, it passes through the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware.

```php
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'flash' => [
                'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now you can access it in your component via:

**Options API**

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <content>
      <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
        {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
      </div>
      <slot />
    </content>
    <footer></footer>
  </main>
</template>
```

**Composition API**

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <content>
      <div v-if="message" class="alert">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
      <slot />
    </content>
    <footer></footer>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

export default {
  setup() {
    const message = computed(() => usePage().props.value.flash.message)
    return { message }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted 'msg' from rooms.index with Response $request and assigned to a prop. like $msg = $request->session()->get('msg');

Comment: Your answer just saved me from going mad. Thanks

Comment: is there a way to "delete" the message after a certain time?

Comment: I believe flash messages are deleted from the server memory after the request. If you  want to hide the message in the UI you'll need a setTimeout in the Vue component to handle this. I think it's better to use a Vue component that supports qeues for this, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-notification

Comment: @MatheusDal'Pizzol Can you write this answer for composition API too

Comment: Read more about Shared data - https://inertiajs.com/shared-data

Comment: To have the answer complete, I used this layout:
<div class="  m-6"><div class="bg-green-200 text-green-900 rounded-lg shadow-md p-6 pr-10" style="min-width: 240px;"><div class="flex items-center"> Something  happened... </div></div></div>
Taken from https://laravel-news.com/building-a-flash-message-component-with-vue-js-and-tailwind-css
Otherwise, class alert not recognized.